# Intel x86_64 assembly, how to floor double from xmm register to int?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, intel

How can I do that? It would be best if result will be in e*x register.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You've asked several trivial questions which you could answer by just looking at how a C compiler does it.  From there, you can look up the instructions it used, and decide which ones you want to actually use.  (There are about a zillion different rounding functions in libm, so picking the right one in the first place isn't always easy).

Using `-O3 -ffast-math` gets most simple libm functions inlined (since it doesn't have to potentially set `errno` on NaN, or crap like that).

Anyway, compiler input and output, from [gcc 5.3 on the Godbolt Compiler Explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-O3+-Wall+-Wextra+-fverbose-asm+-march%3Dhaswell+-mno-avx+-ffast-math',source:'%23include+%3Cmath.h%3E%0A%0Aint+floor_double(double+x)+%7B+return+(int)+floor(x)%3B+%7D%0A%0Aint+truncate_double(double+x)+%7B+return+(int)+(x)%3B+%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3):

```
#include <math.h>

int floor_double(double x) { return (int) floor(x); }
    roundsd xmm0, xmm0, 9
    cvttsd2si       eax, xmm0
    ret

int truncate_double(double x) { return (int)x; }
    cvttsd2si      eax, xmm0
    ret
```

See the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki for links to Intel's instruction set reference manual pdf.  There's also an [unofficial HTML version](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/) generated from the PDF.

[`cvttsd2si` truncates towards zero](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTSD2SI.html), like [`trunc()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/trunc), instead of rounding towards -Infinity like the [`floor()` function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/numeric/math/floor).

That's why `floor()` compiles to SSE4.1 `roundsd` when that instruction set is available.  (Otherwise it has to fiddle with the rounding mode, as you can see by removing or changing the `-march` option on godbolt).

---

There are also packed versions of the conversion instructions, like [CVTTPD2DQ`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTPD2DQ.html) to do 2 at once.  (Or 4 with AVX).

Answer (score 0):

To floor doubles use [CVTTPD2DQ—Convert with Truncation Packed Double-Precision FP Values to Packed Dword Integers](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CVTTPD2DQ.html).

`CVTTPD2DQ` does floor/trunctate two `double`s to two `int`s in an XMM register.

The corresponding *Intel C/C++ Compiler Intrinsic* is

```
____m128i _mm_cvttpd_epi32(__m128d a)
```

To put the result to a GPR(General Purpose Register) like `EAX`, you can use the following instructions:

```
CVTTPD2DQ xmm0, xmm1 ; XMM1 is the source of doubles
movd eax, xmm0       ; extracts int(0) from XMM0 to EAX
pextrd ecx, xmm0, 1  ; extracts int(1) from XMM0 to ECX
```

Comment: How can I then move result from xmm to f.e. eax register?

Comment: zx485: If that int fit in eax register, will movd eax, xmm0 do the job?

Comment: @formateu: Well, you requested an `int`/`_signed DWord_`=32-bit output in your question. So yes, `MOVD` will copy 32 bits from the lowest bits [31:0] of `XMM0` to `EAX` like explained in the link I provided above. The second `DOUBLE` is provided as _signed integer_ in the bits [63:32] of `XMM0` making `PEXTRD` an appropriate way to access them.

Comment: This is just truncation, not floor, and the OP was probably only looking for scalar (so `CVTTSD2SI` would be a better choice.)  Mentioning the packed version is good, but you need to also mention the normal scalar way.