# Intel x86_64 Assembly: What is good way to convert 32bit integer to 64bit int?

Tags: assembly, int, type-conversion, x86-64

As title says.
My way to do this:

```
; eax holds 32bit integer
sal rax, 32
sar rax, 32
;after operation int is converted (rax holds the same value on 64 bits)
```

Is there more elegant/better/faster way to do this??

Comment: @PeterCodes I think your answer is a valid answer. I guess you can upgrade it to an answer, which can then be accepted. You get extra points :)

Comment: Totally agree with it. @Peter Cordes, thank you for all your help in past few days. All of that was priceless. You have great knowledge.

Comment: @JoeyRoosing: I didn't have time to write it up a full answer earlier.  I decided not to post it as 2-line answer.  I hoped someone else might take the time to write up my comment into a nice answer, so I wouldn't have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**TL;DR**: `movsxd`, or for the eax special-case, `cdqe`.

---

Like I explained in one of your [previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37571892/intel-x86-64-assembly-how-to-floor-double-from-xmm-register-to-int), you can answer these yourself by looking at compiler output.  It's *really* easy to write a function that sign-extends an integer, then go look up the instruction it uses in the manual:

```
#include <stdint.h>
int64_t sign_extend(int32_t a) { return a; }

    movsxd   rax, edi
    ret
```

From [clang -O3 on the Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:clang380,options:'-xc++-Wall+-Wextra+-fno-verbose-asm+-O3+-march%3Dhaswell',source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0Aint64_t+sign_extend(int32_t+a)+%7B+return+a%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0A////+some+other+stuff+you+might+try+to+make+the+compiler+do+different+things%0A%0Aint64_t+g64%3B++//+globals,+so+they+won!'t+get+optimized+away%0Aint32_t+g32%3B%0A%0Avoid+sign_extend_global()+%7B+g64+%3D+g32%3B+%7D%0A%0A%0A//+you+probably+wouldn!'t+notice+cdqe+from+just+looking+at+the+manual+for+movsxd%0Aint64_t+use_cdqe(int32_t+a)+%7B+return+a*3%3B+%7D%0A')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

---

Then you look up [`movsxd`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/MOVSX:MOVSXD.html) in the [instruction set reference](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/), and you're done.  (That's a conversion of Intel's PDF (links in the [x86](/questions/tagged/x86) tag wiki), which has a table-of-contents with a summary line for every instruction.  Text searching in that will often find what you need.)

---

There's a special-case for rax, called [`cdqe`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CBW:CWDE:CDQE.html).  8086 didn't have `movsx` until 386, just the al -> ax `cbw`.

---

This is and other ax-only stuff is why Intel spent 8 opcodes on single-byte encodings for [`xchg ax, reg`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XCHG.html) in 8086.  AMD arguably should have reclaimed these for AMD64, for use in future instruction-set extensions, since AMD64 was the first (and probably only for a very long time) opportunity to break backwards compatibility with 8086 opcodes, or 386's 32bit-mode machine-code.

This is where the single-byte NOP (`90`) encoding comes from: `xchg eax,eax` is recognized as a special-case that's executed efficiently (not free, but cheaper than `mov eax,eax` for example).  In 64bit mode, it doesn't zero-extend eax into rax.  (Intel documents [`nop`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/NOP.html) as a separate instruction (along with the long-NOP encoding), and doesn't mention this special-case behaviour in the entry for [`xchg`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/XCHG.html))

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: that's been in the x86 tag wiki for months :P  If you liked that link, take a look at what else is in there; I've added some good stuff in the past year.

Comment: Good info, It's probably been a year since I lasted checked that page. It was useful then, but I've always looked out for a convenient quick-reference. Glad to see that is on the page now.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: for my own use, I usually just have Intel's pdf version open.  It's really fast to navigate entries in a good PDF viewer, since it has the table of contents built in to the PDF metadata.  So e.g. I can click in the index pane, ctrl-f movsx.  Works great, except you have to remember that all the shifts are in the entry that starts with `sal`...  Felix Cloutier's HTML version makes a mess of the tables/diagrams, and those are where the PDF really shines for vector shuffle instructions, compared to the intrinsics guide.